# VBA code equivalent to Ctrl+[

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a code where I want to select precedent cell(s) (which lie in another closed workbook saved on my desktop). Basically I'm looking for VBA equivalent of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>

Comment: Pressing Ctrl+[, opens closed workbook from the desktop. Range(xyz).directdependents/showprecedents don't.

Comment: You can't "select" something in a closed file. Do you mean to get the values from the closed workbook without opening it?

Comment: Yes, if the formula in the open workbook is linked to a value in the closed workbook. I want to reach to that closed workbook via a macro

Answer (score 0):

Range("A5").DirectDependents.xyz, without opening the workbook properly to do this could prove tricky, I would suggest also looking at the XML files for the spreadsheet perhaps.

[image]

Comment: This works if the precedent cell is in the same workbook, not otherwise

Comment: The only way to find inter-sheet dependents and precedents seems to be to put up the navigation arrows and navigate them, which tricky to get right and is very slow.  I was hoping ctrl+[ would work.  Note ctrl+] does not work intersheet.  Send keys would do it, but a horrible hack.